# closures share variable between objects

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to implement a silly code, a base object which has a 'private' member(closure variable), and two objects based on that object. it appears the two objects manipulate the same closure variable

```
Obj = (function(){

    var count = 0;    

    function getCount(){
        return count;
    }

    function setCount(c) {
        count = c;
    }

    return {
        getCount : getCount,
        setCount : setCount
    }

}());

obj1 = Object.create(Obj);
obj2 = Object.create(Obj);

obj1.setCount(10);
obj2.getCount(); // 10? that's.. not so good
```

So, I the original Obj code is only executed once, which explains this somewhat.

My question :

Is there any way of keeping a 'private' variable while creating multiple objects off a closure? I couldn't find any clever workaround and I would love to avoid setting that variable as publicly accessible.

Comment: you need to execute a function upon instantiation for that

Comment: If you want to have a "private scope" per object, you have to create a new one whenever you create an object, not just once.

Comment: hey, As I said I'm pretty sure I understand WHY this occurs, was wondering if there's a way around it :)

Comment: You already seem to know what the solution is: Don't execute the `Obj` related code just once.

Comment: You only have one closure scope. Inheriting from `Obj` doesn't matter, the `obj1.setCount` closure is *exactly the same function* as `obj2.setCount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you have

```
+-------+\
| obj1  | \
+-------+  \ +-------+---getCount---\
             |  Obj  |               var count
+-------+  / +-------+---setCount---/
| obj2  | /
+-------+/
```

The two objects share a common prototype `Obj`, which has two methods that both access the same `count` variable.

what you want is to have two separate `count` variables and a separate `Obj` for each with its own methods that close over `count`.

To do this, just turn the IIFE function into a named function, and ditch the `Object.create`.

```
function Obj(){

    var count = 0;    

    function getCount(){
        return count;
    }

    function setCount(c) {
        count = c;
    }

    return {
        getCount : getCount,
        setCount : setCount
    }
}

obj1 = Obj();
obj2 = Obj();

obj1.setCount(10);
obj2.getCount(); // 0
```

Now you have this:

```
+-------+---getCount---\
| obj1  |               var count
+-------+---setCount---/

+-------+---getCount---\
| obj2  |               var count
+-------+---setCount---/
```